# Maven Dependency jar for BuildPluginManager

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

In my maven plugin Mojo Java file, I am importing interface [BuildPluginManager](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/BuildPluginManager.html) using following line:

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager;
```

This line gives following error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/username/git/path/to/plugin/my-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/company/product/repo/my_maven_plugin/ExecutorExampleMojo.java:[25,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class BuildPluginManager
  location: package org.apache.maven.plugin
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Also, eclipse shows this error in the beginning of the file:

```
The type org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

From what I understand, it means that the dependency jar/war that has this interface `BuildPluginManager` is not there in the POM file. My question is, which dependency do I need to pull in to use this interface? How do I find that dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include dependency on [`org.apache.maven:maven-core`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven%7Cmaven-core%7C3.2.5%7Cjar):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find this out by [searching the Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav), `By Classname`. 
Just put `org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager` into the `Classname` input field.

[image]