# Maven: Adding maven-core dependency Causes PlexusContainerException

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

I am trying to use [Mojo-Executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor) and trying out the example of `copy-dependencies` on that link. According to the instructions, I have included it as dependency in my maven plugin POM and have created a mojo as following:

```
package executors;

import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager;
import static org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.*;

public class SomeNameMojo extends AbstractMojo{

    @Component
    private MavenProject mavenProject;

    @Component
    private MavenSession mavenSession;

    @Component
    private BuildPluginManager pluginManager;

}
```

Because it has `BuildPluginManager`, I have to include `maven-core` as dependency (as below) since it needs that dependency. (See the [question I asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493372/maven-dependency-jar-for-buildpluginmanager) for that).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Problem is after adding that particular dependency in the POM file of the maven-plugin, My tests stop working and give following error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.name.name2.maven.plugin.somemavenplugin.SomeMojoTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.343 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDeleteFilesTrue(com.name.name2.maven.plugin.somemavenplugin.SomeMojoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.269 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Error starting container
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.start(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:795)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusTestCase.setUp(PlexusTestCase.java:121)
```

I am explicitly seeing this error only after adding the dependency. If I comment out the dependency `maven-core`, I get the error saying it does not recognize the symbol `BuildPluginManager` (which is why I need the dependency in the first place).

I have also tried a few different versions of `maven-core`, but same error. How do I make the error go away while keeping the dependency?

EDIT 1:
The test code: (please note that it works as intended when the `maven-core` dependency is not introduced.

```
public class DeleteFilesInBundleDirMojoTest extends AbstractMojoTestCase {

    String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File fileToBeDeleted = new File(userDir + "/test_1_file.txt");
    File fileNotToBeDeleted = new File(userDir + "/test_3_file.txt");

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // required
        super.setUp();
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // required
        super.tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     *             if any
     */
    public void testDeleteFilesTrue() throws Exception {
        Boolean temp = fileToBeDeleted.createNewFile();
        assertNotNull(temp);
        assertTrue(fileToBeDeleted.exists());

        File fileDir = new File(userDir);
        String[] wildcardFilters1 = { "test_1*.txt", "test_2*.txt" };
        List<String> deletedFiles1 = PackagingUtils.deleteFiles(fileDir, wildcardFilters1);
        assertFalse(deletedFiles1.isEmpty());
        assertFalse(fileToBeDeleted.exists());
    }

    public void testDeleteFilesFalse() throws Exception {
        Boolean temp = fileNotToBeDeleted.createNewFile();
        assertNotNull(temp);
        assertTrue(fileNotToBeDeleted.exists());

        File fileDir = new File(userDir);
        String[] wildcardFilters2 = { "test_1*.txt", "test_2*.txt" };
        List<String> deletedFiles2 = PackagingUtils.deleteFiles(fileDir, wildcardFilters2);
        assertTrue(deletedFiles2.isEmpty());
        assertTrue(fileNotToBeDeleted.exists());
        assertTrue(fileNotToBeDeleted.delete());
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the test code as relevant to the error log shared.

Comment: A mojo usually has an parent `AbstractMojo`...

Comment: please see the edit @nullpointer

Comment: @khmarbaise I have edited to include that. Even with that, I am facing the same issue. I just had to add `execute` method which I have kept empty.